# Why could a material look different in rendered result and in viewport Rendered shading mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, procedural

This is my first node group and I can't figure out why the material showing up in the viewport looks different than what is rendering. Please, can someone help?

Rendered material:

[image]

Viewport material:

[image]

Here is the .blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/psnl2vj0j4vvc4s/blenderMetal_mat.blend?dl=0

Comment: Wow, that is really interesting.  I couldn't find anything obvious.  I wonder if it's a bug with Pointiness, or maybe they optimize some calculation in the viewport to make it faster at the expense of accuracy?